# Office 365: Authenticating between Dynamics CRM Plugin and Sharepoint

Tags: c#, office365, dynamics-crm-online, sharepoint-online

I am trying to authenticate to Sharepoint 2013 from a Dynamics CRM 2013 plugin, all within a single Office 365 environment. 
I am ultimately trying to copy an email attachment from Dynamics CRM to Sharepoint (Post Email Attachment Create Async). 
So far this journey has been fraught with obstacles.

- I have gone to AppRegNew.aspx to get a client id and secret.
- I have built a web request and posted the information to 
  `mycompanyname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx` but receive a 403 Forbidden error.
- I can't use CSOM because I am unable to deploy the Sharepoint.Client.dll to the Dynamics CRM Online
- I'm not sure what the scope in the request paramaters should be

Here is a code excerpt from what I have so far:

```
string clientId = "myclientid";
string clientSecret = "asecretstring";

this.request = string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=list.read", Uri.EscapeDataString(clientId), Uri.EscapeDataString(clientSecret));

WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(OAuthUri);
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.request);
webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream outputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    // get token from the response
}
```

I would really appreciate some direction in authenticating
between the two Office 365 systems.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the UserAgent string like so - "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)" on the request